RuntimeError : Expected ASGI message 'websocket.accept' or 'websocket.close', but got 'http.response.start'
After updating my FastAPI version to  fastapi[standard] to use fastapi-cli I got an error regarding sockets. I searched all the threads but couldn't find a solution. Could someone help me please?
# my socket.py file

import socketio

server = socketio.AsyncServer(
    cors_allowed_origins="*",
    async_mode="asgi",
    logger=True,
    engineio_logger=True,
    ping_interval=30, 
    ping_timeout=60
)


# app.py

app = FastAPI(
        title="My App",
        lifespan=LifeSpan
    )

    # ----mount socket------
    sm = socket.socketio.ASGIApp(socket.server, socketio_path="socket.io")
    app.mount("/ws", sm)
    app.sio = socket.server

